# How to get all text having certain pattern in UIAutomator

Tags: appium, android-uiautomator, uiautomatorviewer

I have a list of contacts which is scrollable. I want to get all contacts starting with *+880* while scrolling. How can I use regex here?
Here is my code

```
     ui_str = 'new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).getChildByText(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.TextView"), "+880")'
     current_group_members = admin_device.driver.find_elements_by_android_uiautomator(ui_str)
```

I've also resource id of each element  *com.test.communicator:id/phoneNumberTxt*. Can I get all elements with this id?
I've tried to use **find_elements_by_id** but It gets only visible items. I need all elements in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You could search through the children by selecting those matching a text regex.  See UiSelector.textMatches(...) for getting UiAutomator to use regex:

Per Javadoc:

> Set the search criteria to match the visible text displayed in a layout element, using a regular expression. The text in the widget must match exactly with the string in your input argument.
> https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/uiautomator/UiSelector#textmatches